# I am trying to print specific array element

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to print array element which is content "Great food" word only.here my array

> ```
> Array
>   (
>    [0] => Great food and Great Atmosphere! Will definately go back before I leave!!
>    [1] => Great place
>    [2] => Great place
>  )
> ```

Comment: R U referring to `$array[0]` if the variable name is `$array`?

Comment: And what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with `strpos()`

```
$arr = array('Great food and Great Atmosphere! Will definately go back before I leave!!', 'Great place', 'Great place');
$findme ='Great food';
foreach($arr as $a) {
 if(strpos($a, $findme) !== false) {
  $newarr[] = $a;
 }
}
print_r($newarr);//Great food and Great Atmosphere! Will definately go back before I leave!!
```

if you want only `Great food` match change `if(strpos($a, $findme) !== false) {` to `if($a == $findme) {`

Comment: Oh! This might have been what he was looking for. Please guys, learn English before posting.

Comment: who said the OP is mean?

Comment: @kevinabelita thank you for remind me . i have done that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [array_filter](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function.

```
function match_string($element){
  return strpos($element, 'Great food');
}

$matches = array_filter($input_array,"match_string");
```